# How to include external configuration resources to classpath in Spring (Spring Boot)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have 3rd party library that is configured by placing properties file on the root of the classpath. That library is using `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.properties")` to load that file. As it is 3rd party, **it is unmodifiable**. I have placed that configuration file into **external** `resources` directory (not to be mistaken with `resources` from eg. Maven's or Gradle's directory structure.

Directory structure is like this.

[image: Dir stricture]

How to run/configure Spring boot to include content of `resources` directory to the classpath so `getResourceAsStream` wil work?

On SE application I would simply do `java -jar myApp.jar` with classpath in MANIFEST and that would work.

EDIT:

Just a word of clarification - putting configuration file inside project resources (along sources) is missing the whole point. I want to keep configuration externalized.

Comment: How are you building and running your application?

Comment: Can you show the tree structure of your proyect?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson build - gradle, run - CLI `java -jar (...)`

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can do it:

**1.- Change your `spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration` to enable the Spring Boot PropertiesLauncher:**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**2.- Launch your Spring Boot Application setting the location of the external properties file:**

`java -jar -Dloader.path=PATH_TO_PROPERTIES_FOLDER spring-ms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Assuming this folders:

```
/home/user/
     |--- file.properties
     |--- spring-mg-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You should launch it like this: `java -jar -Dloader.path=/home/user spring-ms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: Configuration should stay externalized. This solves nothing.

Comment: Your assumption looks acceptable, I will try to adapt this for Gradle and Ill let you know did it work.

Comment: Great, I tested it with Maven and it works perfectly. I guess you won't have any problem to adapt it to Gradle.